# How to make the sum of all completed times in the task at feature level in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, effort

I need to calculate effort for each feature in my backlog.

Every sprint or iteration I must make the sum of all completed work time of the tasks and manually add to the parent feature.
I have not found anything can make it automatically. Do you know if something exists?

I am following this lisk:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#sum-of-remaining-work-per-developer

But I cannot grouping either by User Story or Feature...
Here the query:
[image]

Among the other columns I added the parent:

[image]

I wanted to add the feature but I cannot find the correct Column

Then I created a chart:

[image]

But here I cannot find either the parent column or the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps may sum only on the backlogs. Check this link: [Display rollup progress or totals in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process). Additionally, you may try to use [Excel integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel) or [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi).

Comment: Thank you... I have solved with the first link.. even if now, I do not understand the sense of the Effort field on the feature.... Now I must delete that field otherwise some confusion can happen