# Update the Remaining and Completed Work fields of PBI Automatically

Tags: azure-devops

I have PBI and tasks under this PBI, both of them have original estimate.
Now during work I update the tasks Remaining and Completed Work fields.
How to reflect the sum of those fields to the PBI Remaining and Completed Work fields automatically?

For example:

**Before work start:**

PBI
Remaining Work: 50
Completed Work: 0

TASK
Remaining Work: 50
Completed Work: 0

**After some work:**
I update the task to be 40/10 ,how to update the PBI automatically.

Comment: it is not supported. Check this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942278/how-to-make-the-sum-of-all-completed-times-in-the-task-at-feature-level-in-azure

Comment: Hi @Alexander Gorelik, have you checked the suggestions below and follow [the feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-calculated-fields-in-tfs/365423)? Currently, it's suggested to use rollup columns as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that you are using a custom Scrum process, since the default PBI work item does not have the "Remaining Work" and "Completed Work" fields.

Currently, fields that can be automatically accumulated based on other WIs are not supported. Someone has already submitted such a feature request [Support for calculated fields and roll-ups](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-calculated-fields-in-tfs/365423). In order to meet user needs, Azure DevOps released rollup colums in backlog view. See [Track the progress of work using Rollup columns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/track-the-progress-of-work-using-rollup-columns/) and [Display rollup progress or totals in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) for the detailed info.

To use rollup colums, go to backlog view. Click **Column options** -> Add a rollup column -> Configure custom rollup.

[image]

Follow the screenshot below to configure custom rollup.

[image]

Then you can see the sum of the completed work and the remaining work.
[image]